# YouTube v3 Javascript API - authentication issue - "Refused to display"

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to run the Google [Javascript YouTube API](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/javascript) samples, and I get the following error when the page (search.html) loads:

Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=[XXX]...F%2Flocalhost&response_type=token&state=366536542%7C0.931065623&authuser=0' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

I'm running this from a host that's authorized in the "JavaScript origins" section of my credentials in Google Developer Console.

The only change I've made to the code was to enter my credentials in auth.js

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to put your Client ID in auth.js.

```
var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
```

Plus, to configure Redirect URIs and JavaScript origins in https://console.developers.google.com for localhost :

```
Client ID   XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com

Email address   XXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Client secret       XXXX

Redirect URIs   http://localhost/oauth2callback

JavaScript origins  http://localhost
```